# How to parse the response from requests.get()?

Tags: python, python-requests

The below code returns response as text format:

```
val = https://service-smthing.com/info.txt
response = requests.get(val).content
print response
```

```
Response -

tag = unique-tag
buildNo = 1234
description = some description
```

How to parse `buildNo` from such plain text response? Also, I tried and unable to parse or use the response functions like `loads()`, `response.headers()` etc. the same way as json response.

Comment: See the: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ - Official documentation of requests library.

Basically you need to assign `response = requests.get(val)`. Then you should be able to get headers from the response like: `response.headers`

Comment: @Rozart thanks for the info. I have some val (URLs) which outputs json type response hence used get(val).content and able to parse/deserialize the json objects through loads(). My ques is more concerned towards how to parse this  tag, buildNo from the text/plain response

Comment: by using regex, `(?<=buildNo.{3}).*?(?=\n|$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the content on your own, but it's just splitting on the equal sign for each line:

```
response = requests.get(val).content.decode('utf-8')
result = {}
for line in response.splitlines():
    k,v = line.split(' = ')
    result[k] = v

print (result)
```

Returns:

```
{'tag': 'unique-tag', 'buildNo': '1234', 'description': 'some description'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict comprehension:

```
response = '''Response - 

tag = unique-tag
buildNo = 1234
description = some description'''

data = {line.split(' = ')[0]: line.split(' = ')[1] for line in response.splitlines()[2:]}
```

Result:

```
print(data)
{'tag': 'unique-tag', 'buildNo': '1234', 'description': 'some description'}
```